# Escape probability for a randomly oriented, single fixed size step from a random coordinate inside a square

Tags: probability, geometry

I have a square with side length $ s $.

A (uniformly) random coordinate $ c = (x,y) $ inside this square is the origin of a (uniformly) randomly oriented vector of fixed length $ l $.

[image]

Vector endpoints can end up both within the square and outside of it, depending on their orientation and $ c $. The escape probability for a point is not the same everywhere, it depends on their position.

A vector starting closer to the center/halfway along the side of the square has a lower probability than one in the corner to land outside.

Point p here can reach the sides but not the corner, everything closer to the corner can do both and therefore has an even higher probability.

[image]

So how does this probability distribution $ P_{escape}(s,l,x,y) $ look like?

Can it be used to express the average expected escape probability for large amounts of randomly chosen vectors analytically?

$ P_{escape}(s,l) = ? $

##### Some possibly irrelevant notes:

In the special case where $ l<s/2 $, there exists in the center of the square a region (here in green) where vectors, regardless of orientation, cannot reach the edge. In this special case, there is also a segment of the square edges that have probability 1/2

Also, if $ l = 0 $, then $ P(s,l) = 0 $, or if $ l > \sqrt{2*s^2} $, then $ P(s,l) = 1 $

Comment: Hint: Assume the bottom left corner of the square is the origin. Consider any point $(x,y)$ and draw a circle with radius $l$. Then any point on the circle be written as $(x + l \cos \theta, y + l \sin \theta)$ for $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$. Can you find the range of $\theta$ for which this point lies outside the square?

Comment: @sudeep5221 if you look at the range of $\theta$, the calculus gets quite messy. I've posted an alternative approach as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify things a little, let's make $s=2$ and we'll consider the square $S$ with vertices $(\pm1,\pm1)$.

Say the start point of the vector is $P(u,v)$ and its angle (measured anticlockwise from the positive $x$-axis, as usual) is $\theta$.

Then the endpoint of the vector is $Q(u+l \cos \theta,v+l \sin \theta)$.

It's tempting to pick $P(u,v)$ and work out the range of $\theta$ that makes $Q$ outside $S$, but this makes calculations very messy.

It's better to fix $\theta$, and consider the ranges of $u$ and $v$.

Let's restrict $\theta$ to be in the range $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ (this will actually cover all cases, by symmetry). This means both $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ are positive.

We need to consider the cases $l \le 2$ and $l>2$ separately.

---

Case $l \le 2$

For the point $Q$ to be *inside* $S$, we need both
$$-1<u<1-l \cos \theta$$

and

$$-1<v<1-l \sin \theta$$

These inequalities define a rectangle, with area
$$(2-l \cos \theta)(2-l \sin \theta)$$

So, for a given $\theta$, the probability the point $Q$ is *inside* $S$ is
$$P(\theta) = \frac{(2-l \cos \theta)(2-l \sin \theta)}{4}$$

(the ratio of the areas of the rectangle and the whole square).

Now, to find the overall probability, we need to integrate:
$$\begin{align} P(\text{inside})&=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{(2-l \cos \theta)(2-l \sin \theta)}{4} d\theta \\
&= 1+\frac{l(l-8)}{4\pi}\end{align}$$

So the probability we want (one minus this) is
$$\boxed{P(\text{escape}) = \frac{l(8-l)}{4\pi}}$$

---

Case $l>2$

This method needs a slight adjustment for $l>2$. Note that now, if $P=(-1,-1)$ and $\cos \theta > \frac{2}{l}$, $Q$ will *always* be outside $S$.

This observation tells us what to do, though; we just change the limits for $\theta$ in the integral:

$$\begin{align} P(\text{inside})&=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{\cos^{-1} \frac{2}{l}}^{\frac{\pi}{2} - \cos^{-1} \frac{2}{l}} \frac{(2-l \cos \theta)(2-l \sin \theta)}{4} d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi} \left(8\sqrt{l^2-4}-16\cos^{-1} \frac{2}{l} + 4\pi - 8 - l^2 \right)
\end{align}$$

So finally, in this case,
$$\boxed{P(\text{escape}) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \left(8 + l^2  - 8\sqrt{l^2-4}+16\cos^{-1} \frac{2}{l} \right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

The final position $(X,Y)$ is $(C_x + l\cos\Theta,C_y + l\sin\Theta)$ where: $C_x,C_y \sim U(0,s)$, $\Theta \sim U(-\pi,\pi)$,
$l\cos(\Theta)\sim\operatorname{Arcsine}(-l,l)$.

Let $L_x=l\cos\Theta$ and $L_y = l\sin\Theta$
$L_x = \lambda \Rightarrow L_y=\lambda\tan\Theta$

$$\begin{align}F_{L_y}(l_y)&=P(L_y\leq l_y)\\&=
P(\lambda\tan\Theta\leq l_y)\\&=
P\left(\Theta\leq\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{l_y}{\lambda}\right)\right)\\&=
F_\Theta\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{l_y}{\lambda}\right)\right)\\&=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{l_y}{\lambda}\right)+\pi\right)
\end{align}$$

$$\therefore P(L_y|L_x=\lambda)=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2+l_y^2}\\
$$
$$\begin{align}
P(L_x) &=
\frac{1
}{\pi\sqrt{(l_x-(-l))(l-l_x)}
} \\&=
\frac{1
}{\pi\sqrt{l^2-l_x^2}
}
\end{align}
$$
$$\begin{align}
P(C_y|L_x) &= P(C_y)
\end{align}
$$
$$\begin{align}
P(C_y+L_y|L_x) &=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f_{C_y}(y−l_y)f_{L_y}(l_y)dl_y}\\&=
\int_{y}^{y-s}{\frac{1}{s}\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2+l_y^2}dl_y}\\&=
\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y-s}{\lambda}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\lambda}\right)}{2 \pi s}
\end{align}
$$
$$\begin{align}
P(C_y+L_y) &=
\int_{y}^{y-s}{\frac{1}{s}
\frac{1
}{\pi\sqrt{l^2-l_y^2}
}dl_y}\\&=
\frac{\sin^{-1}\left(
\frac{y-s}{l
}\right)-\sin^{-1}\left(
\frac{y}{l}\right)
}{\pi s
}
\end{align}
$$
$$\begin{align}
P(L_x|Y)&=
P(L_x|C_y+L_y)\\&=
P(C_y+L_y|L_x)
\frac{P(L_x)}{P(C_y+L_y)
}\\&=
\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(
\frac{y-s}{l_x
}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(
\frac{y}{l_x
}\right)}{2 \pi s
}
\frac{
\frac{1
}{\pi\sqrt{l^2-l_x^2}
}
}{\frac{\sin^{-1}\left(
\frac{y-s}{l
}\right)-\sin^{-1}\left(
\frac{y}{l}\right)
}{\pi s
}
}\\&=
\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(
\frac{y-s}{l_x
}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(
\frac{y}{l_x
}\right)}{2\pi\left(\sin^{-1}\left(
\frac{y-s}{l
}\right)-\sin^{-1}\left(
\frac{y}{l}\right)\right)\sqrt{l^2-l_x^2}
}
\end{align}
$$
$$
P(C_x|Y)=P(C_x)
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\therefore P(X|Y)&=
P(C_x+L_x|Y)\\&=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f_{C_x}(x-l_x)f_{L_x}(l_x)dl_x}\\&=
\int_{x}^{x-s}{
\frac{1}{s
}
\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(
\frac{y-s}{l_x
}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(
\frac{y}{l_x
}\right)}{2\pi\left(\sin^{-1}\left(
\frac{y-s}{l
}\right)-\sin^{-1}\left(
\frac{y}{l}\right)\right)\sqrt{l^2-l_x^2}
}dl_x}
\end{align}
$$

This is as far as I got,

$$\begin{align}P(X,Y)&=P(X|Y)P(Y)\\
&=P(C_x+L_x|C_y+L_y)P(C_y+L_y)
\end{align}
$$

And,
$$\begin{align}P(0\leq X\leq s, 0\leq Y\leq s)&=\int_0^s{\int_0^sP(X=x,Y=y){dx}dy}
\end{align}$$

This should at least sketch you a solution